# How to generate auto generated sequence no in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have one requirement. I already have a table named WorkOrder. In this table there is a column Named WorkorderId set as primary key and identity. The next one is voucherNumber. Now I want to generate voucherNumber automatically. The condition is voucher number will not repeat. E.g., first I insert 2 rows into the table and after that I delete the 2nd entry. The next time my voucher number should be 3. Again i insert 3 more entries then after that my voucher no should be 6. Then i delete one row from this table after that my voucher number should be 7. If i delete the last row (I mean 7) then next time the voucher number should the same.

Answer (score 3):

Use `IDENTITY(...)` when creating the column. This will make a field auto-increment its value.

You'll have to drop the column first in case that it already exists. There is no (clean) way to make this happen on already existing columns.

For further information and examples you can check out http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

Edit: Sorry, I have overlooked the info that you are already using `IDENTITY(...)` on the PK column. Unfortunately SQL-Server can only have a single column with the IDENTITY property per table... So in this case you'll have to make use of a trigger.

This is an example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CountRows 
ON TestCount 
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
UPDATE TestCount  SET Cnt = Cnt +1 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID from inserted)
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to enter an IDENTIFIER to the record, it is best to use `uniqueIdentifier` type column. It is a string constant in the form `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`, in which each x is a hexadecimal digit in the range 0-9 or a-f. For example, 6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00C04FC964FF is a valid uniqueidentifier value.

On insertion, you can simply proceed as follows;

```
Insert into MyTable 
(WorkorderId, WorkName) values (NewId(), 'Test')
```

Using this, you can be sure the Id is globally unique.

Comment: Actually i want to show the voucher number in the user interface. how can i select the very next voucher number in this case.

Comment: if you want to insert a particular value, you'll have to make a calculated column.

Comment: i want to select the particular voucher number from the above requirement

Comment: I would be careful when using a GUID, especially if you use them on your clustered index. They are very large and when indexed, cause a great deal of fragmentation. The other thing I dislike about them is that they make debugging much more difficult b/c they are not easily remembered/entered. Generally, they should only be used when there is a true business need for them (e.g. something akin to home-grown replication). See this post for more info: http://tinyurl.com/p7lfyx5.

Comment: Agree with you @Gizmo but its the only proven way to create a real unique identifier, wothout great deal / calculation on insertion since the `newid()` function is provided.

Comment: @Nadeem_MK all true. If the values will only be used on the local server, using NEWSEQUENTIALID might be a better choice, in that it is ever increasing, negating the fragmentation. Unfortunately, it is only unique on the current machine.